# Remove specefic tag from xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

I have a webservice and it's response is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <contractor-management> 
 <request-attributes> <corp-id>abcd</corp-id></request-attributes>
 </contractor-management> 
 </string>
```

I am getting the above response but I want to remove the string tag line. So it should be like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <contractor-management> 
 <request-attributes> <corp-id>abcd</corp-id></request-attributes>
 </contractor-management>
```

Due to some reason("-" cannot be used as a part of variable name), I am creating the above like this:

```
        string x;
        x = "<contractor-management>";
        x += "<request-attributes> ";
        x += "<corp-id>abcd</corp-id> ";
        x += "</request-attributes> ";
        x = "</contractor-management>";
```

Comment: Have you tried using a XML serializer? Generating XML manually seems error-prone.

Comment: If you design the response yourself and your not bound to certain Tag names get rid of the "-". There are XML Readers out there having a problem with that.

Comment: business requirement is there...i cannot get rid of it...some prior things are there where i need to fit my code

Comment: Google `XDocument` and then use that - it will make your life better.

Comment: i am not an expert, but i used the attribute[XmlElement("DesiredName")] attribute on the method and used SOAPUI to check the response, and I was getting the desired response.

Comment: Use `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`. It's much easier to use. Don't ever use string manipulation to create XML. The rules are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like below code, where **xmlContent** is your current xml contents

```
   XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
   xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlContent);
   XmlNode firstChild=xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("string")[0];
   XmlNode secondChild = firstChild.FirstChild;
   xmldoc.ReplaceChild(secondChild, firstChild);
```

You can also save this modified xml to a file

```
xmldoc.Save(@"modified.xml");
```